# How do I reference an input field in another project in WCF asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, web-services

I have 2 projects in a solution. One called RentalService and one called RentalClient.
I'm trying to use the RentalClient to input data (Rate, Days) which will be sent to RentalService to be processed and return Price by multiplying rate by days.

Here is the code behind for the service:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;

namespace RentalService
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ICalcPrice
    {
        [OperationContract]
        CalcPrice CalculatePrice(double price);
    }
    [DataContract]
    public class CalcPrice
    {
        [DataMember]
        public double Rate {get; set;}
        [DataMember]
        public int Days {get; set;}
        [DataMember]
        public double price {get; set;}
    }
}
```

and here is the service code: I didn't complete it because I'm stumped :/

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;
using RentalClient;

namespace RentalService
{
    public class CalcPrice : ICalcPrice
    {
    public txtRate.text 

    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your client code? All I see is service side code, that is not complete. What is it you want help with?

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to use the RentalClient to input data (Rate, Days) which
>   will be sent to RentalService to be processed and return Price by
>   multiplying rate by days

You need to define a method which accepts `Rate` and `Days` as parameter. Define that method in your interface `ICalcPrice` and the implement in your class `CalcPrice`

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ICalcPrice
{
    [OperationContract]
    CalcPrice CalculatePrice(double price);

    [OperationContract]
    CalcPrice CalculatePrice(double price, int days);

}
```

Then in your class:

```
public class CalcPrice : ICalcPrice
{
     public CalcPrice CalculatePrice(double price, int days)
     {
       //your logic
      }
```

Comment: I still get error when trying to get variables from the client. How do I reference these?

Comment: @msmis88, try testing your service in [WcfTestClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552364.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Each time you make changes on your contract on your server-side, don't forget to update your references on your client side.

[image]

This will build you a new wsdl, which will contain the updates of your Contract. After this you will be able to use your CalculatePrice method with 2 params.